# Android R CameraX with scoped storage getting image column id after capture

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, android-camerax, scoped-storage

The app I am working on needs a new lease on life and one renewing task for Android R and above: is getting the id of an image taken by CameraX from scoped storage.  The purpose being to save the id in a datatable for upload later.  
With regards to permissions the App only saves files to its own external directory, so no permissions are necessary.
After CameraX has captured the image using the following `OutputOptions`:

```
val contentValues = ContentValues()
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, imgName)
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + "Custom directory")

val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
        activityContext.contentResolver,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL),
        contentValues
    ).build()
```

The `onImageSaved` CameraX callback method from the `imageCapture.takePicture` object returns an `ImageCapture.OutputFileResults`:

```
override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
        val savedUri = output.savedUri
```

**This is where things get fuzzy**; I have the `Uri` of the saved image.  I tried using the `Uri` to retrieve the image column id by searching for the file name with:

```
val projection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
)

val selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + "=?"
return contentResolver.query(
    savedUri,  // the image capture uri
    projection,  // query columns
    selection,  // query
    arrayOf(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + "Custom directory"),  // query arguments
    null  // order by
)?.use { cursor ->

    if (cursor.count > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val fileName =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
            Log.d(TAG, "index $fileName")
            if (fileName.equals(displayName)) {
                return@use cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID))
            }
        }
    }
    return@use null
}
```

I consistently get `null` results.  So I tried the following content uri in the place of the `savedUri`:

```
val contentUri =
    MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
```

This also only gives `null` results and 0 `cursor.count` columns.  Can someone please point me in the right direction on why the above file queries are giving `null` results?

**Edit 1**
After reading `blackapps` comment I went and read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) again.  My understanding of scoped storage it seems is definitely lacking.  I was using `getExternalFilesDir` before to get an output path and all was fine until I added `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` <s>which according to the below comment is seen as public</s>.  That is when I started to meddle with the above `MediaStore` api and got tangled into thinking to much or little depending on my point of view.
**Edit 2**
Some more reading of the [App specific sources](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) where it does not state anywhere that `getExternalFilesDir` method will be removed in Api 32 or 33.  So it can be used to even save in public directories.  The example given is:

```
val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName)
```

Further:

> It's important that you use directory names provided by API constants like DIRECTORY_PICTURES. These directory names ensure that the files are treated properly by the system.

****<s>Caveat to the above quoted documentation is that this excludes DIRECTORY_DCIM: Why is this not in the documentation?</s>****
****Edit 3:****
A good question to ask when uncertain if you are dealing with scoped storage is whether the files are:

> Shareable media files (images, audio files, videos)

Comment: `With regards to permissions the App only saves files to its own external directory, so no permissions are necessary.` Well you are saving to public DCIM directory and for that you need the normal WRITE permission. As such it has nothing to do with scoped storage too.

Comment: `I have the Uri of the saved image. I tried using the Uri to retrieve the image column id` Why are you after an id if you have the uri?

Comment: Is there a way to get a path from the uri `content://media/external/images/media/52`? With regards to your first comment the documentation says `The app will have unrestricted access to both internal and external storage for reading and write operations`.  Is `DCIM` not external?

Comment: `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) which according to the below comment is seen as public.` No. getExternalFilesDir() is not public. How many subdirs you create there they are never public.

Comment: `that getExternalFilesDir method will be removed in Api 32 or 33. So it can be used to even save in public directories.` No. getExternalFilesDir() is non public. And it will not be removed and that has never and nowhere been suggested.

Comment: Where you use MediaStore with DCIM you are going for the public dir.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the clarification.  Can you make your comments the answer showing my lack of understanding of the storage Api?